# How to display a PIL image object in Django view?

Tags: django, image, view, python-imaging-library

Im using [a library](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) on github to generate a qrcode myself rather than using an api but I'm having a hard tme understanding how to render a PIL image object (which is the default image renderer).
So far I have this:

```
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.pure import PymagingImage
img = qrcode.make('Some data here', image_factory=PymagingImage)
```

but I'm stuck when it comes to displaying it as an image on my main page view.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

EDIT:
Also would really appreciate some clarification on the html syntax if possible:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img src="{% static "some.jpg" %}" alt="somename" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After generating QR-code you need to return it as image in response.
In one of my projects I use this library.
Here I have:

```
def generate_qr_code(data, size=10, border=0):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
                       box_size=size, border=border)
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    return qr.make_image()
```

And the view:

```
@render_to()
def return_qr(request):
    text = request.GET.get('text')
    qr = generate_qr_code(text, 10, 2)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="image/png")
    qr.save(response, "PNG")
    return response
```

Then you can pass your text to view, and image returns as result.

---

**UPD:**

I have an templatetag to show qr in my template.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('qrcode/qr_tag.html', takes_context=True)
def get_qrcode_image(context, text, size):
    url = reverse('generate_qr')
    return {'url': url, 'text': text, 'size': size}
```

And the template `'qrcode/qr_tag.html'`:

```
<img src="{{url}}?size={{size}}&text={{text}}" />
```

So in result you can include your QR-code in this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        {% get_qrcode_image 'some text to decode' 320 %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, if possible please could you help me understand how i get it into the html? I modified the question above also :)

Comment: If you're still around could you just clarify what the `@render_to()` decorator does? I don't see it referenced anywhere else. Or do you mean for me to replace it with the name of the view I am using? Thanks again :)

Comment: It's decorator from django-annoying, but since you return response manually, you don't need `@render_to`.

Answer (score 2):

The question's titles and answers aren't a good match for each other as neither make any mention of PIL and instead reference some other library. This question insists on being the first listed when searching simply for an example on displaying a PIL generated image in a Django view.

Here's an updated answer that answers the original question.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from PIL import Image

def my_view(request):

    image = Image.new('RGB', (128,128), 'green')

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/jpeg')

    image.save(response, "JPEG")

    return response
```